# CONCATENATE Multiple cell in one

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, textjoin

I want to merge A to Z cell in one with line break,
Please tell me it's short form
every two sell merge with line break A - Z

````
=CONCATENATE(A1,"
",B1,"
",C1,"
",D1,"
",E1,"
",F1,"
",G1,"
",H1,"
",I1,"
",J1,"
",K1,"
",L1,"
",M1,"
",N1,"
",O1,"
",P1,"
",Q1,"
",R1,"
",S1,"
",T1,"
",U1,"
",V1,"
",W1,"
",X1,"
",Y1,"
",Z1)```
````

Comment: `=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,A1:Z1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10); 1; A1:Z1)
```